# Python version of a Perl regular expression

Tags: python, regex, perl, scripting

I have this Perl regular expression and I want to convert it to Python.

The regex I want is a search and replace that finds text and converts it to upper case. It also must be the first occurring result.
Perl regex:

```
open FILE, "C:/thefile.txt";
while (<FILE>){
    # Converts "foo yadayada bar yadayada"
    #       to "FOO  bar yadayada"
    s/(^.*?)(yadayada)/\U$1/;
    print;
}
```

The Python regex I have is not working correctly:

```
import re
lines = open('C:\thefile.txt','r').readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = re.sub(r"(yadayada)","\U\g<1>", line, 1)
    print line
```

I realize the `\U\g<1>` is what isn't working because Python doesn't support `\U` for uppercase.. so what do I use!?!

Comment: Documented what the Perl code does for the Python programmers who aren't familiar enough with Perl.

Comment: Are you sure that's not suppose to be `s/(yadayada)/\U$1/`?
`

Answer (score 3):

`re.sub` can take a function, which processes each match object and returns a string. So you can do it like this:

```
In [4]: def uppergrp(match):
   ...:     return match.group(1).upper()
   ...: 

In [5]: re.sub("(yada)", uppergrp, "abcyadadef", count=1)
Out[5]: 'abcYADAdef'
```

Working with regexes in Python is less convenient, but Python programmers tend to be less keen to use regexes than Perl coders.

Comment: That works perfectly but I am confused as to how you would use it with multiple replacements. How could I include multiple functions in    re.sub ?  How could I concatenate words to the end of the uppercase words?

Comment: @user1399782 Do you want to do a series of things to each replacement? You can make the function as complex as you want. Do you want to do different replacements of different parts? You can either call `re.sub` several times, or build a more complex regex and check the match inside the function.

To add something after the uppercase word, you can just make the function `return match.group(1).upper() + 'something'`.

Comment: For that input, the Perl code outputs `ABCdef`, not `abcYADAdef`.

Comment: @ikegami: If you want that, make the regex `(^.*?)(yada)`, so that group 1 is `'abc'`

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to sub can also be a function, meaning if regex language in python cannot accomplish what you want (or at least makes it very difficult) you can just define your own function to use instead.

eg.

```
re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), string)
```

edit: The function gets passed a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)

Comment: We hit essentially the same answer within a few seconds of each other. A win for 'one obvious way to do it'. ;-)

Comment: Indeed, though you seem to have just beaten me to it.